Create stacked overlapping tikz vectors (matrices)
I wonder if it is possible, using tikz, to create partially overlapping vectors (ideally using the matrix library), of different colors and different content. To better describe what I would like to achieve, I attached an image below.
All the solutions I found (like this or this) use a repeating pattern, which only partially fulfill my objective.

EDIT:
This is what I achieved so far, but I don't know if it is the most efficient way to proceed.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, calc}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    [%
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=0pt,text height=4pt,text width=4pt},
    ]

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    xshift=28pt,
    yshift=28pt,
    ] (d1)
    {
      |[fill=red]| {0} \& |[fill=red]| {0} \& |[fill=red]| {1} \& |[fill=red]|{1} \\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    xshift=5pt,
    yshift=5pt,
    behind path,
    ] (d2)
    {
      |[fill=green]| {1} \& |[fill=green]| {0} \& |[fill=green]| {1} \& |[fill=green]|{0} \\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    behind path,
    ] (d3)
    {
      |[fill=orange]| {1} \& |[fill=orange]| {1} \& |[fill=orange]| {0} \& |[fill=orange]|{0} \\
    };

    \path (d1.east) -- node[auto=false, rotate=45]{\ldots} (d2.east);
    \path (d1.west) -- node[auto=false, rotate=45]{\ldots} (d2.west);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,raise=.5mm}] (d3.south west) -- ($(d3.west) + (0pt, 34pt)$) node[midway, left=4mm] {$\binom{n}{k}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




Have a look at the tikz manual for shapes.multipart

Also look for \pic.

As usual here please show what you have tried so far ....

@Mensch added some edits

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I looked into it, but I didn't see any way for it to be useful. Could you expand on this?

I take it you're not a mathematician if you're using ISO style? behind path isn't doing anything here. auto is false by default. Consider using the positioning library rather than coding absolute coordinates. The backgrounds library may or may not be helpful.

@cfr which style would you suggest for math? I used the positioning library while improving my code. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient, nicer looking, approach.

@tigerjack I just know that mathematicians think the ISO style wrong-headed and don't use it. The positioning library etc. should be more efficient in terms of typing. As to nicer looking, what did you have in mind?

This is my attempt, based on the comments. I hope it will help someone.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, decorations.pathreplacing, calc, fit, positioning,
  arrows.meta, shapes, patterns, patterns.meta}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[%
    local bounding box=scope0,
    shift={(-100pt, 5pt)},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=0pt,text height=6pt,text width=4pt},
    ]
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    ] (start){
      |[fill=white]| {0} \& |[fill=white]| {0} \& {\ldots} \& |[fill=white]|{0} \\
    };
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}
    [%
    local bounding box=scope1,
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=0pt,text height=6pt,text width=4pt},
    ]

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    xshift=20pt,
    yshift=20pt,
    ] (d1)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]|{1} \\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=3pt of d1,
    xshift=-15pt,
    ] (d2)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]|{0} \\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of d2,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (d3)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]|{0} \\
    };

    \path (d1.south) -- node[auto=false, rotate=65]{\ldots} (d2.north);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,raise=.5mm}] (d3.south west) -- ($(d3.west) + (0pt, 34pt)$) node[midway, left=4mm] (binom) {$\binom{n}{k}$};
  \end{scope}
  % 
  \begin{scope}[%
    local bounding box=scope2,
    shift={(100pt, 35pt)},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=0pt,text height=6pt,text width=4pt},
    ]


    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    xshift=20pt,
    yshift=20pt,
    ] (id1)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {2} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {3} \\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=3pt of id1,
    xshift=-15pt,
    ] (id2)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {2}\\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of id2,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (id3)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {1}\\
    };
    \path (id1.south) -- node[auto=false, rotate=65]{\ldots} (id2.north);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace, raise=-2pt}] (id1.north east) -- ($(id1.east) - (0pt, 36pt)$) node[midway, right=0mm] (binom2) {$\binom{[n]}{k}$};
  \end{scope}
  % 
  \begin{scope}[%
    local bounding box=scope3,
    shift={(100pt, -35pt)},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=0pt,text height=6pt,text width=4pt},
    ]


    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    xshift=20pt,
    yshift=20pt,
    ] (id1)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {1} \\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=3pt of id1,
    xshift=-15pt,
    ] (id2)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {3}\\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of id2,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (id3)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {2} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {3}\\
    };
    \path (id1.south) -- node[auto=false, rotate=65]{\ldots} (id2.north);
  \end{scope}

  \node[fit={(scope1.west) (scope2.north east) ($(scope3.south east) + (18pt, 0pt)$)}, very thick, solid, rounded corners, draw, green!95!black] (box123) {};
  \draw[green,
  style={shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,thin,pattern={north west lines}, pattern color={green!95!black}}
  ] (box123.south west) -- ($(box123.south) - (10pt, 0)$) -- ($(box123.west) - (0, 15pt)$);


  \draw[thick,-Stealth] (scope0.east) -- node[midway, anchor=south] (uu) {${s}$}  (box123.west);
  \coordinate (m) at ($(scope1.east) + (2pt, 0)$);
  \draw[thick] (scope1.east) -- (m) 
  node[draw, circle, inner sep=0.5mm, fill=black] {};
  % 
  \draw[thick,-Stealth] (m) --  (scope2.west) node[anchor=south, draw, circle, dashed, inner sep=1.5pt] (qi) {$\symbf{\underline{i}}$};
  \draw[thick,-Stealth] (m) --  (scope3.west) node[anchor=south, draw, circle, dashed, inner sep=1.5pt, yshift=3pt] (qic) {$\symbf{\underline{\bar{i}}}$};

  \begin{scope}[%
    local bounding box=scope4,
    shift={(200pt, -15pt)},
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    every node/.style={anchor=base,text depth=0pt,text height=6pt,text width=4pt},
    ]

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    xshift=70pt,
    yshift=70pt,
    ] (j1)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {2} \\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j1,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j2)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {3} \\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j2,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j3)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {2} \\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j3,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j4)
    {
      |[fill=violet!95!black]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!95!black]| {3} \\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=3pt of j4,
    xshift=-15pt,
    ] (j5)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {2}\\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j5,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j6)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {2} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {3}\\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j6,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j7)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {1}\\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j7,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j8)
    {
      |[fill=violet!66!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!66!white]| {3}\\
    };

    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j8,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j9)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {2}\\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j9,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j10)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {1} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {3}\\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j10,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j11)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {2}\\
    };
    \matrix[
    matrix of math nodes,
    below=-12pt of j11,
    xshift=-5pt,
    ] (j12)
    {
      |[fill=violet!25!white]| {0} \& |[fill=violet!25!white]| {3}\\
    };
    \path (j4.south) -- node[auto=false, rotate=65]{\ldots} (j5.north);
    %
    \node[fit=(j1.north east) (j12.south west), rounded corners, thick, solid, rounded corners, draw, violet] (box4) {};
    \draw[violet,
    style={shape=regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,thin,pattern={crosshatch dots}, pattern color={violet}}
    ] (box4.south east) -- ($(box4.south) - (10pt, 0)$) -- ($(box4.east) - (0, 15pt)$);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[thick,-Stealth] (box123.east) -- node[midway, anchor=south, dashed] (uu) {${u}$}  (scope4.west) node[anchor=west, draw, circle, dashed, inner sep=1.5pt] (box4) {$\symbf{\underline{j}}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


